# Why are InputStream instances closed when referenced within an ObservableMap?

Tags: java, inputstream

I have ObservableMap in which resource files added.

```
private ObservableMap<String, InputStream> resourceFilesData;
resourceFilesData = new ObservableMapWrapper<String, InputStream>(
    new HashMap<String, InputStream>()
);
```

And InputStreams added in such way:

```
resourceFilesData.put(f.getName(), new FileInputStream(f));
```

and finally when I want to use streams, they appear closed!

Why? I cant find reason.
Maybe, there some whey to handle moment, when stream get closed? (for debugging)

how streams are used:

```
private void pack() throws JAXBException, IOException {
    HashMap<String, InputStream> resources = new HashMap<>();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("../" + fwData.getFileName() + ".iolfw"));
    File xml = fwData.marshal();
    InputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(xml);

    resources.put(xml.getName(), xmlStream);
    resources.putAll(resourceFilesData);
    for (Map.Entry<String, InputStream> data: resources.entrySet()) {
        InputStream input = data.getValue();
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(data.getKey()));

        for (int readNum = 0; (readNum = input.read(buf)) != -1; ) {
            zos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        input.close();
    }
    zos.close();
    resources.remove(xmlStream);
    xml.delete();
}
```

trace:
    http://pastebin.com/hE21ECL9

Comment: Please, provide source code and stack trace. I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Which line is 476th?

Comment: pack() function starts at 463. 476 - is nested loop.

Comment: I debbuged and in a line:

    _resources.putAll(resourceFilesData);_

streams already closed, even before I put them in a new container

Comment: **2 Durandal** Because I also have import functionality, that returns  me map of InputStream. How you can judge of a style without full source?! If you haven't answer on my concrete question - better skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason of that behaviour. But you can try to debug the problem using inherited class:

```
class FileInputStreamInh extends FileInputStream {

    public FileInputStreamInh(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        ^^^breakpoint here
    }
}
```

So, instead of creation `FileInputStream`, you should create `FileInputStreamInh`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. It was my mistake - I closed it earlier.